# how to bind a databse value in html ul,li tags Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to bind a database value in html list tags Asp.net C#

i need to bind the database particular column in html list tag
how .i am using asp.net c#..without repeater control 
 i don't know how to handle it

Answer (score 0):

Roy',

You cannot directly bind datasource object to an html control not even if its runat server.

there is two ways to solve your problem.

1. You can use client-side scripting.
2. Else You can use AngularJS, it will be easy enough.

**OR you can use this code :**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <%
                // Here I have created dummy data-object(DataTable), but You can fetch data from Database.
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable(); 
                dt.Columns.Add("id"); dt.Columns.Add("name");
                dt.Rows.Add("1", "Val1");
                dt.Rows.Add("2", "Val2");
            %>
            <% foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dt.Rows)
              {%>
            <li id="<%= row["id"].ToString() %>">
                <%= row["value"].ToString() %>
            </li>
            <%} %>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```